# how many natural numbers on a sphere

Tags: diophantine-equations

how many natural solutions are there to the following equation: 
$$ \sum_{i=0}^k x_i^2 = n$$
where $n,k \in\ \Bbb{N}$
i well like to get a answer for every n and k, but could do with just $k=2,3$.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86178/integer-lattice-points-on-a-sphere and the links there.

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88826/integer-coordinate-set-of-points-that-is-a-member-of-sphere-surface?lq=1

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html